# Checking if a value has not been initialized always returns value is not initialized, even if it is

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to jQuery-like script that supports selectors, show, hide, text, and html methods.
Running a test, no matter which method I call, it always throws a custom "No Element Selected" error. How do I fix this?
The full code is here --> https://jsfiddle.net/7ado13vg/

The relevant code is below

```js
var storingAttributes = {};

class MONEY {
  constructer(string) {
    try {
      //check for action
      if (string != null) {
        //Check Selection Type
        storingAttributes.selectorArray = string.split('')

        if (storingAttributes.selectorArray[0] == '#') {
          storingAttributes.selectionType = 'id';

          storingAttributes.selectorArray.splice(0, 1);
        }

        if (storingAttributes.selectorArray[0] == '.') {
          storingAttributes.selectionType = 'class';

          storingAttributes.selectorArray.splice(0, 1);
        }

        if (storingAttributes.selectorArray[0] != '#' && storingAttributes.selectorArray[0] != '.') {
          storingAttributes.selectionType = 'tag';
        }

        //Select Elem
        if (storingAttributes.selectionType == 'id') {
          storingAttributes.selectedElem = document.querySelector(string);
        }

        if (storingAttributes.selectionType == 'class') {
          storingAttributes.selectedElem = document.querySelectorAll(string);
        }

        if (storingAttributes.selectionType == 'tag') {
          storingAttributes.selectedElem = document.querySelectorAll(string);
        }

      }

    } catch (error) {

    }
}
//The reason I checked what was being selected is because querySelectorAll returns an array, and I do not believe that ids are supported

  //trying to use my method 'show'
  show() {
    try {
      if (typeof storingAttributes.selectedElem == 'undefined' || storingAttributes.selectedElem == null) {
        throw "No Element Selected";
      } else {
        if (storingAttributes.selectionType == 'tag') {
          for (n = 0; n < storingAttributes.selectedElem.length; ++n) {
            storingAttributes.selectedElem[n].style.display = 'block';
          }

          return;
        }

        if (storingAttributes.selectionType == 'class') {
          for (n = 0; n < storingAttributes.selectedElem.length; ++n) {
            storingAttributes.selectedElem[n].style.display = 'block';
          }
  
          return;
        }
  
        if (storingAttributes.selectionType == 'id') {
          storingAttributes.selectedElem.style.display = 'block';

          return;
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `constructor` simply assigns/initializes a value for `selectionType`, `selectedElem`, and `selectorArray` in the object `storingAttributes`

When you log `storingAttributes`, it returns an empty object.

Comment: A few things here... Your code doesn't show anything that would cause `storingAttributes.selectedElem` to be defined in the first place so of course it will always say that it's `undefined`. Is there more code that does populate it? Next, you are using `try/catch` inappropriately. `try/catch` is really only for code that could fail **through no fault of the developer** (think network outages that prevent connections to other resources, like a database). In your case, you can code this so it never encounters an error, so `try/catch` is never needed (cont).

Comment: Next, instead of those `return` statements at the end of each `if` branch, use `else if` on the alternative branches, which will accomplish the same thing, but with the intended syntax. Last, just test for `if(storingAttributes.selectedElem)` rather than specifically testing for `undefined` or `null`..

Comment: Why are you using a global variable instead of a class property in the `MONEY` class?

Comment: Please post a [mre] here, not at a remote site.

Comment: Why are you writing your own selector parser instead of using `document.querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: I added `console.log(storingAttributes)` to your fiddle, it shows an empty object. So the problem is the code that's supposed to fill it in.

Comment: @Barmar if that is the problem, then `storingAttributes.valueName` doesn't initialize a variable, so how would I initialize the variable? Would declaring them in storingAttributes work?     Would simply just adding `selectedElem: null` into storingAttributes work?

Comment: @ScottMarcus the `try...catch` is there is someone use `new MOENY.method` without initializing the constructor, which would cause an error to be thrown. The `try...catch` is to catch that error and not execute the code.

Comment: @Farrathan `try/catch` should not be used in this way. Instantiating a class is something that a developer should know to do and if they don't, they will get a native error from the runtime anyway. `try/catch` should not be used as a "catch all". There are performance implications from its use.

Answer (score 0):

The following replaces the code you've posted to show how much simpler it can be written and without erroneously using `try/catch`.

I understand that it doesn't answer your question, but the code you are working with is really so unnecessarily excessive, it's hard to sift through it to find your problem without refactoring it. Simpler code is easier to debug.

```js
var storingAttributes = {};

// Just test for the non-existance of a value
if (!storingAttributes.selectedElem) {
    throw "No Element Selected";
} else {
  // switch is more concise when you have a single value to 
  // check against multiple possible values
  switch (storingAttributes.selectionType){
    case "tag":
      // And since you want to do the exact same code if
      // it's "tag" or "class", we'll allow fall through here
    case "class":
      // The Array.prototype.forEach method makes looping much simpler
      storingAttributes.selectedElem.forEach(function(item){
        item.classList.add("block");
      });
      break;  
    case "id":
      storingAttributes.selectedElem.classList.add("block");
  }
}
```

```css
/* Avoid inline styles which lead to duplication of code.
   Instead, use CSS classes where possible. */
.block { display:block; }
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm creating a primitive version of jQuery, so I need all the code to be in js. If I injected css using js, would that work?